# Error:Execution failed for task ':appName:processDebugResources'.?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

after adding some images ressources and make a new build i get this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':appName:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   '/home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt'' finished with
>   non-zero exit value 1

Answer (score 0):

take care about images or other resources that have a name containing special characters like parteciperò.png for example because that names will fail the APK build when ProcessdebugAssets step.

just rename your resources that have special characters

Answer (score 0):

1) use only .png images
2) don't use any special characters in image name except  _ (underscore)
3) don't use any capital letters inside the image name